# Can I use iBooks on my MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, books

I'd love to be able to use iBooks on my laptop. Is that possible? Maybe if I install Lion?

Answer (score 4):

No, it's an iOS application.  It will not run on OS X.

To read DRM-free e-books on your Mac, there are 3rd party Apps like Calibre. But even they can't read the DRM-encrypted books from the iBooks store.

Comment: I agree.  A lot of people are hoping for an OS X version of iBooks. I wouldn't be surprised if it appeared at some point.